# Position div right to a table

Tags: css

I have the following layout:

[image]

I want to position the div right to the table. I would like to control the vertical (relative to the top) and horizontal (relative to the vertical center of the page).

Anybody willing to drop a working CSS example?

[Current status using jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eAV6/)

Comment: Please, for the love of the Standard, don't use that table as a container for the whole page.

Comment: You are talking about placing the div to the left, yet your example shows the div to the **right**. And also, what @KyleSevenoaks said.

Comment: Corrected the left / right problem :) thx. Totally agree about the table that it should not be used, but you know, sometimes you get code from other sources that you can't edit so you have to work around what you have.

Comment: That's funny because I have never seen any source code that I couldn't edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this

**Css**

```
.contant{
width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:solid 3px red;
  position:relative;
}
.out{
width:50px;
  height:50px;
  border:solid 3px green;
position:absolute;  right:-65px;
  top:100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="contant">

  <div class="out"></div>

</div>
```

***[Live demo](http://tinkerbin.com/z0XuRF4w)***

**Updated** -----------------Now you can used to this -----

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="contant"> 
<div class="out"></div>        
</div>
</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: @ValentinDespa, yes but you probably **shouldn't** have a table. Tables are for tabular data, not for layout.

Comment: you can used to table in div because  if u used to positioning in table than some problum creating ...........

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann I know I shouldn't have a table, but I *have* one and I need to look for a fix given the situation.